# How to use json attribute in a toggle with swiftUI list?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, toggle

I developed a SwiftUI app for iPhone/iPad/Mac. The app lists my films (first view) with information such as a note of each film and if the film was seen.
I have a JSON file with:

1. id : Int, unique identifier
2. nom : String, title of film
3. idL : String, first charachter of title
4. note : Int, note of each film (between 0 and 10)
5. isShow : Bool, indicate if the film was seen or not

I created a toggle to only display films where isShow=false, **but I was unable to link this toggle with my JSON property...**

Here is my project : https://github.com/thomjlg/Films-APP

JSON file : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thomjlg/0782e9e8e27c346af3600bff9923f294/raw/9705fb0c6b40eae59578755b86e331bea257972b/films2.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe when you're saving the `movies` you don't reload the `userData`.

```
Toggle("Film", isOn: self.$movie.isShow)
    .onTapGesture {
        self.userData.fetcher.save(movies: self.userData.movies)
        self.movie.isShow = !self.movie.isShow
        print(self.movie.isShow)
    }
```

`fetcher.save(movies:)` just saves your movies but `UserData` is created only once and movies are loaded only in `init`:

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView
    .environmentObject(UserData())
)
```

```
init() {
    fetcher.load { (movies) in
        if let movies = movies {
            self.movies = movies
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, you're probably right, i am a beginner in swiftUI and i do not know what to do to correct this...

Comment: You can have a function in userData called `load` with `fetcher.load` inside. And you can call it from `View` whenever you want to reload your data.

Comment: ok thanks, but my problem is that when i call self.$movie.isShow in the toggle, it does not work... because it's not known... Could you explain it to me ?

Comment: One of the ways can be to use `@State private var isToggleOn = false` and use it in the toggle. Then use `self.movie.isShow = isToggleOn`.

Comment: that's what i was thinking about, where do I write ```self.movie.isShow = isToggleOn```? like where i wrote  ```@State private var isToggleOn = false```?

Comment: You can do it in `.onTapGesture` as you have now [here](https://github.com/thomjlg/Films-APP/blob/master/listeFilms/listeFilms/ContentView.swift). Just instead of `self.movie.isShow = !self.movie.isShow` do `self.movie.isShow = self.isToggleOn`.